# Merge [jdt] and [eclipse-jdt]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

The two tags, [jdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdt) and [eclipse-jdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-jdt), are for the exact same subject and have the same tag wikis.  One of them should be merged with the other.

I personally think that [eclipse-jdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-jdt) is more descriptive, but [jdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdt) has more questions in it.  Yet [eclipse-jdt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse-jdt) has more followers.

Comment: I'd say eclipse-jdt is a better tag.