# Tag synonyms - [twiml] and [twilio-twiml]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[Twiml](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-is-twilio-markup-language-twiml) is Twilio's XML-based markup language for call routing inside their systems.

There are two tags for questions about this language: [twiml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twiml) tag has 285 questions, and [twilio-twiml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twilio-twiml) has 30.

Similar to the discussion around [`ecplise-jdt` and `jdt`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274990/merge-jdt-and-eclipse-jdt) (and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329149/tag-synonyms-jdt-and-eclipse-jdt)), I propose making `twiml` a synonym of `twilio-twiml`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started writing an answer by stating that we can't add a synonym in that direction, because [twiml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twiml) has more than 1.25 times the number of questions in [twilio-twiml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twilio-twiml), but surprisingly, it went through and I was able to create a synonym. Either the underlying check has changed (which is a welcome one), or there's some other criteria at play (which would be nice to know), which I am not sure, but what I am sure is that I don't know how the system work.

I synonymized the tags, in the direction which you mentioned, that is, [twiml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twiml) (x 286) → [twilio-twiml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twilio-twiml) (x 30).